# Pagination in Codeigniter with sql and html table

Tags: php, codeigniter, pagination

I have a view containing a html table that display data retrieve from the database. Is it possible to go about doing a pagination for it?

Code for the view

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title></title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="row" ng-app="appcolor">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <!-- Section for tabs-->
                <div class="tabbable">
                    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                        <li class="active"><a href="#home_banner" data-toggle="tab">Home Banner</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>

            <!-- Section for tab content-->
            <div class="tab-content">
                <div class="tab-pane active" id="home_banner">
                    <fieldset>
                        <!-- Section for managing home banner -->
                        <legend>Manage Home Banner</legend>
                            <?php if($this->session->flashdata('notification')) {echo '<div class="alert alert-success">'.$this->session->flashdata('notification').'</div>'; } ?>
                            <?php if($banners != NULL) { ?>
                            <form action="<?php echo base_url().'backendBanner/update_banners'; ?>" method="POST">
                                <table style="" class="table table-striped">
                                    <tr>
                                        <th>Banner Image</th>
                                        <th>Title</th>
                                        <th>Description</th>
                                        <th>Is Active</th>
                                        <th>Seq Num</th>
                                        <th>Viewed By</th>
                                        <th>Link</th> 
                                        <th>Mobile Link</th> 
                                        <th>Delete</th>
                                    </tr>
                            <?php } ?>
                            <?php foreach($banners as $banner) { ?>
                                    <tr>
                                        <input type="hidden" name="banner_path[]" value="<?php echo $banner['banner_path']; ?>">
                                        <!-- Display the banner image -->
                                        <td style="width:170px;"><?php echo "<img style='width:150px; height:100px'class='gc_thumbnail' src='".base_url()."../home_banner_images/".$banner['banner_path']."' style='padding:5px; border:1px solid #ddd'/>"; ?></td>
                                        <!-- Display the banner title -->
                                        <td style="width:170px;">
                                            <input name="banner_title[]" type="text" value="<?php echo $banner['banner_title']; ?>" style="width:180px;">
                                        </td>
                                        <!-- Display the banner desc -->
                                        <td style="width:170px;">
                                            <input name="banner_desc[]" type="text" value="<?php echo $banner['banner_desc']; ?>" style="width:180px;">
                                        </td>
                                        <!-- Drop down list to select whether the banner is active -->
                                        <td style="width:60px;">
                                            <select name="is_active[]" style="width:60px;">
                                            <?php 
                                                echo "<option value='0'"; if($banner['is_active'] == 0) {echo "selected";}; echo ">".'0'."</option>";
                                                echo "<option value='1'"; if($banner['is_active'] == 1) {echo "selected";}; echo ">".'1'."</option>";
                                                echo "</select>"; 
                                            ?>
                                        </td>
                                        <!-- Drop down list to select the sequence number -->
                                        <td style="width:75px;">
                                            <?php echo '<select name="seq[]" style="width:60px;">'; 
                                                for($count =1 ; $count <= count($banners); $count ++)
                                                { 
                                                    echo "<option value='$count'"; if($banner['seq'] == $count) {echo "selected";}; echo ">".$count."</option>";
                                                }
                                            ?>
                                            </select>
                                        </td>
                                        <!-- Drop down list to select the banner can be view by which group of users-->
                                        <td style="width:130px;">
                                            <select name="viewed_by[]" style="width:120px;">
                                            <?php 
                                                echo "<option value='members'"; if($banner['viewed_by'] == 'members') { echo "selected"; } echo ">".'Members'."</option>";
                                                echo "<option value='non-members'"; if($banner['viewed_by'] == 'non-members') { echo "selected"; } echo ">".'Non-Members'."</option>";
                                                echo "<option value='both'"; if($banner['viewed_by'] == 'both') { echo "selected"; } echo ">".'Both'."</option>";
                                                echo "</select>"; ?>
                                        </td>
                                        <!-- Text field for user to input the banner url link -->
                                        <td style="width:230px;">
                                            <input name="url[]" type="text" value="<?php echo $banner['url']; ?>" style="width:180px;">
                                        </td>
                                        <!-- Text field for user to input the banner mobile url link -->
                                        <td style="width:230px;">
                                            <input name="murl[]" type="text" value="<?php echo $banner['murl']; ?>" style="width:180px;">
                                        </td>
                                      </tr>
                            <?php } ?>
                            <?php if($banners != NULL) { ?>
                                </table>
                    </fieldset>
                </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Code for controller

```
class backendBanner extends CI_Controller 
{

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('backend_banner_model');
        $this->load->helper('url');
        //$this->load->model('product_model');
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $this->landing_banners_upload();
    }

    function escapeQuote($var)
    {
        if (isset($var)){
            $string = str_replace("'","''",$var);    
        }
        return $string;
    } 

    public function landing_banners_upload()
    {
        /*if ($this->session->userdata('admin_logged_in') == 1)
        {*/

            $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
            $config['upload_path'] ='../home_banner_images';//This directory is under base url,
            $config['overwrite'] = true;

            $directory = '../home_banner_images/';
            if (!file_exists($directory)) 
            {
                mkdir($directory, 0777, true);
            }

            $this->load->library('upload', $config);

            if (!$this->upload->do_upload())
            {
                if($this->input->post('userfile'))
                {
                    $data['error']= $this->upload->display_errors();
                }
                $data['banners'] = $this->backend_banner_model->get_landing_banners();
                $this->load->view('layout/header');
                $this->load->view('backendBanner/landing_banners_upload_view', $data);
                $this->load->view('layout/footer');
            }
            else
            {
                $data['upload_data'] = $this->upload->data();
                $file_name = $data['upload_data']['file_name'];
                if(!$this->backend_banner_model->landing_banner_exist($file_name))
                {
                    $this->backend_banner_model->insert_banner_image($this->upload->data());                
                }
                redirect(base_url()."backendBanner/landing_banners_upload");
            }
}}
```

Code for the model

```
class backend_banner_model extends CI_Model {

    public function __construct ()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->db = $this->load->database('online', TRUE);
    }

    //Section for home banner (category)
    /* Get the list of banner from the category of "home_banner */
    public function get_landing_banners()
    {
        $this->db->select('*')->from('banner')->where('banner_category', 'home_banner');
        $data = $this->db->get();
        if ($data->num_rows() > 0) {
        return $data->result_array();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what part of the pagination docs don't you understand?

Comment: I am not sure how can I go about using pagination from controller to model and back to view.

Comment: did you read the docs?